# CRM: Javascript to Check Email Validation and Prevent Saving if not Valid

Tags: javascript, crm, preventdefault

On CRM 2013 on-premise, I'm working to write a javascript that checks for email validation. The field can contain a list of email address, however if the email is not valid, it will not let the users save the form.

I got the splitting and validating to work fine now.

However I continue to have problems to prevent users from saving the form.

On the OnChange, I check the box on the "Pass execution context as first parameter"

I user the preventDefault() function as suggested by an MSDN article however I keep getting error message "Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of undefined or null reference".

Any idea is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
function EmailTest(EmailField)
{
var Email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
if(Email.test(EmailField))
    {
    return true;
    }
else
    {
    return false;
    }
} 

function CheckEmailString(context)
{
try
{
    var EmailString = context.getEventSource().getValue();
    if (EmailString != null)
    {
        var separator = [" ", ",", ";", "|"];
        var EmailArray = EmailString.split(separator);
        var Flag = true;

        for(var i = 0;i < EmailArray.length;i++)
        {
            if(!EmailTest(EmailArray[i]))
            {
                Flag = false;
                break;          
            }
        }
        if(Flag != true)
        {
            alert("The list of emails entered contain invalid email format. Please re-enter");
            context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
catch(err)
{
    alert(err.message);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you get the error

> Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of undefined or null reference

because the [getEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/279ca720-e304-4e51-b99f-91722431c2c8#BKMK_getEventArgs) is available only when you are inside the `save` event, it's not available inside `onchange` event.

You should add the validation check also inside the save event if you want to stop the save.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest you might try updating it to the full version of the method ie 
Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs.preventDefault().

I understand when working in CRM you have to reference use the full names in order for your function to see the prevent default method.

Hopefully that helps but if not good luck in seeking a solution

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actually I tried Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs.preventDefault() and still getting an error... not sure where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: BTW At the risk of stating the obvious, in my experience CRM does perform its own version of Email validation which works well- for example it won't allow you to save an email address that doesn't contain an @ symbol and a full stop. And if you make the email field "business required" (i.e. mandatory) then the user won't be able to save a record without a valid email address. Just make sure to select an email address as the field type and not a regular single line text field